# Which one to choose and when? One-v/s-One and One-v/s-All classification for multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, multi-class

In case of multi class classification task, how do we decide which among the two options viz. one-v/s-all and one-v/s-one do we choose for model building?

Is there some criterion based on which we decide to choose either of the two options for good accuracy? Otherwise should we run using both the options and choose the one that gives higher accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

I have limited experience on multi-class but I usually (try to) test both methods. The problem is that most implementations only implement one alternative ([libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) based implement one-vs-one) so you have to implement the other "by hand" (that is create an outer loop that call the binary SVM with the appropriate classes) which is not something you always have time to do. Also there is a problem with this approach - the one-vs-one approach in libsvm use the **same** $\gamma$ and C for all pairwise SVM, so "to be fair" you need to do the same with your implementation of one-vs-all done by hand or you also implement the one-vs-one by hand.